# Laravel withCount specify Column of relation table (API/Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, api, count, eloquent, relation

In my project I created one table POSTS and another POST_VIEWS (the last one got each visits of user and take take ip and post_id)

The relations for my Post is like this :

```
public function view() {
return $this->belongsTo(PostView::class);
 }
```

My API Query is like this :

```
$posts = Post::withCount('view')->get();
```

All of this works but **I need to count the number of IP in the relation table PostView** and i didn't find any way to do something like that...

if anyone have a solution you can save my life...

Comment: You have defined `view` as relation. And you are using views as count related models. So you have to either define `views` as relation or use `Post::withCount('view')->get();`

Comment: Sorry my bad i made a mistake by writing my post, currently the count work but i need to say something like : `withCount('view.ip')`

Comment: A `post` can have multiple `views`, right? Then you have to use a `HasMany` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that directly withCount is used to count other models in direct relation with the current model , as i can see you have a one-to-one post-view relationship *which looks weird* but you can try an alternative solution as this one :

```
$posts = Post::with(['view'=>function($query){
             $query->withCount('ip');
         }])->get();
```

this query will get you back the ip count alongside the 'view' .